# Python MySQL Connector: 'caching_sha2_password' authentication plugin not supported

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

That is the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming projects\Project.py", line 3, in <module>
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\BboyM\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BboyM\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BboyM\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\BboyM\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File "C:\Users\BboyM\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 137, in _do_auth
    packet = self._protocol.make_auth(
  File "C:\Users\BboyM\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 99, in make_auth
    packet += self._auth_response(client_flags, username, password,
  File "C:\Users\BboyM\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 58, in _auth_response
    auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
  File "C:\Users\BboyM\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\authentication.py", line 190, in get_auth_plugin
    raise errors.NotSupportedError(
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported

Process finished with exit code 1
```

That is the code for now, can't even start doing anything because I can't connect.

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=("localhost"),
    user=("root"),
    passwd=("0QDeaWSzcXfgH0"),
)
```

I've tried reinstalling the connector plugins in pip, in Pycharm and changing the authentication method to legacy and nothing seems to work. I'm desperate for help because I can't find the solution that works anywhere. I even downloaded conda and tried instaling the connector with it instead of pip but that didn't help either.